# Site URL redirect is not redirecting to correct page

Tags: force.com-sites, url

There are two communities in the org:

1. Invest [Site URL: https://myorg.force.com/Investigators]
2. Acquired- [Site URL: https://myorg.force.com/Acquired]

I want to create a site URL redirect for first site, so that if a user enters

> https://myorg.force.com/**investigators**

instead of

> https://myorg.force.com/**Investigators**

user will be redirected to correct page.

I have created site url redirect with source url as: `//myorg.force.com/investigators` and target url as:`//myorg.force.com/Investigators`.

But,still is not getting redirected.

I have also tried creating URL redirects in Myorg sites, but no success.

Is there anything that I am missing.

Comment: how can two different communities have a same site URL, I am confused!

Comment: I am sorry about that. Now I have provided correct URL.

Comment: basically, you want the to retain the casing of the domain in sites?

Comment: Yes @RahulSharma

Comment: What happens if you navigate to `https://myorg.force.com/investigators` page? Do you get error Page Not Found, Your purpose is to avoid this error?

Comment: Using `https://myorg.force.com/investigators` shows the error message `https://myorg.force.com/Acquired` is under construction.
      Yes,I do want to avoid this error message and get redirected to `https://myorg.force.com/Investigators` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since any site URL was getting redirected to `https://myorg.force.com/Acquired`,I have added site URL redirects in 'Acquired' site rather than in 'Invest'.

Source URL: `/investigators` 
and Target URL :`https://myorg.force.com/Investigators/login`.

This setting was successfully redirecting to desired page.